# sqlite writing a date into an email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, date

I am exporting a date value from sqlite and placing it into an email.  The date appears like this
279498721.322872

I am using Objective C in an Iphone App.  Does anyone know how to make this export out as a regular date whether it is all number like
2009-02-10 or anything legible?

Comment: What langauge are you using? I know in C# the sqlite drivers handle this sort of thing automatically.

Comment: I just wanted to add that info, Objective C, iphone App.... thx for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  The answer came from my Guru Alex Cone.  He told me to use the following:

```
NSTimeInterval tempInterval = (NSTimeInterval)sqlite3_column_double(statement, 4);
```

The `tempInterval` variable can then be loaded into the the `NSDate` method.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you take the number `279498721.322872` and throw it into an `NSDate` object using `+dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, you get (here in the MDT timezone): `2009-11-09 15:32:01 -0700`, which was just under 4 hours ago.  If that's the time you're expecting, then formatting it is as simple as using an `NSDateFormatter`.

However, the thing to notice is that sqlite (by default) stores dates as textual representations (unless you specify differently in the sql statement).  So the real question here is "where are you getting that number from?"

Comment: Dave, thanks, so far...
 NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy"];
  NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:279498721];
  NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
  NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);

when I try to place tempString where the 2794.... number is at the system errors:
"incompatible type of argument.Any thoughts.Thx

Comment: @Leland - yeah.  2974... is a number (a primitive).  You can't pass in an object there.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("Y-m-d",time(279498721.322872));
```